# In Python, how would I alter a list of times in a text file?

Tags: python

I have a text file that contains many times in the format HH:MM:SS,MM.

```
1
00:00:05,21 --> 00:00:11,53
Thank you Alex Lopez, Alex, all the Alexs
and the Latinx Affinity group for
```

This is a collection of subtitles for a video.  What I need to do is alter the times by a constant amount.  That way, if the video creators want to add an animation to the beginning of the video, all of the subtitles will still line up with the speaker in the video.  Say the animation is 5 seconds, just for instance.
My approach so far is almost certainly inefficient.  I'm new to programming and this is my first real-world use of any programming language to solve a problem.  I'll share the meat of what I have so far to demonstrate due diligence, but I imagine the right way to solve this is much cleaner than what I've been doing.

```
import re
import string

fr = open('project.txt')
text = fr.read()
regex = r"(\d+):(\d+):(\d+),(\d+)"
matches = re.finditer(regex, text, re.MULTILINE)
matchNum = 0
z=[]

def getTimeInts():

    for matchNum, match in enumerate(matches, start=1):

        print ("Match {matchNum} was found at {start}-{end}: {match}".format(matchNum = matchNum, start = match.start(), end = match.end(), match = match.group()))
        for groupNum in range(0, len(match.groups())):
            groupNum = groupNum + 1
            group = match.group(groupNum)
            print ("Group {groupNum} found at {start}-{end}: {group}".format(groupNum = groupNum, start = match.start(groupNum), end = match.end(groupNum), group = match.group(groupNum)))
            q = 0
            r = 0
            s = 0
            t = 0
            if groupNum == 1:
                q = group
            elif groupNum == 2:
                r = group
            elif groupNum == 3:
                s = group
            elif groupNum == 4:
                t = group
            else:
                continue
            toAppend = str(q) + str(r) + str(s) + str(t)
            z.append(toAppend)
            if (enumerate(z) == matchNum):
                return (z)
            else:
                continue
getTimeInts()
print(z)
```

I don't know how much code is appropriate to post, so here's the whole program I have so far. As you can see, I'm young in coding in general.  Any tips or simpler functions or whatever help can be given would be appreciated.  Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [datetime](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/datetime.html).

Basically
1. Convert your timestamp into a datetime object (lets say t1)
2. Create a timedelta object of 5 seconds (lets say t2)
3. Add t1 and t2 (t1+t2)
4. Parse out the resulting datetime object in any way you like

Everything you need is in the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/datetime.html).

```
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
t1 = t1 = datetime.strptime("00:00:05,21","%H:%M:%S,%f") #put your time instead
delta = timedelta(seconds=5) #seconds, minutes, hours, whatever
t1 += delta 
t1.strftime("%H:%M:%S,%f")[:-4] #omitting last 4 digits because milliseconds are 6 digits but we only care about the first 2
```

Answer (score 1):

By using date and time functions in Python and converting your strings into datetime objects:

```
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
from time import strptime
q = 7
time_string = '00:58:05'
a = datetime.strptime(time_string, '%H:%M:%S')
b = a + timedelta(minutes=q)
print(a.time())
print(b.time())
```